# GAS: Error 500 while connecting to an API

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm trying to connect to Cloud Waitress API, a solution for restaurants,

Documentation: https://apidocs.cloudwaitress.com/#orderpromos

It's documentation gives an example on how to connect to the API:

```
curl https://api.cloudwaitress.com/v1/orders \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: YOUR_API_KEY" \ 
  -d `
    {
      "restaurant_id": "xxxxxxx",
      "limit": 10,
      "page": 1,
      "sort": { "created": -1 },
    }
  `
```

I tried to create a Script in GAS to get the information back to a Spreadsheet.

This is my code so far:

```
function GetOrders(){  
  var url='https://api.cloudwaitress.com/v1/orders';
  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers":{
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "SOME-AUTHORIZATION-KEY"
    },
    "payload": {
      "restaurant_id":"SOME-RESTAURANT-ID",
      "limit": 10,
      "page": 1,
      "sort": { "created": -1 }
    }
    /*
    ,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
    */
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());


  var TotalRecord = data["outcome"];
  Logger.log("response: " + response);
  Logger.log("data: " + data);
  Logger.log("TotalRecord: " + TotalRecord);
}
```

However I'm getting a 500 error

> Exception: Request failed for https://api.cloudwaitress.com returned
>   code 500. Truncated server response: {"error":"Internal Error"} (use
>   muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 23, file
>   "Code")

According to their website a 500 error corresponds to:

[image]

I would interpretate the error as if something is wrong of their side, which I doubt.

However, seeing my code I can't figure out what might be missing.

Additional notes:

Output when Mutting exceptions:

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have tried a get?

Comment: @Cooper yeap, same error.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you make the request from somewhere else (not Apps Script)?

Comment: What makes you think it's not a problem on their side?

Comment: @LuisAlbertoDelgadodelaFlo Hi Luis, I believe you also opened another thread with 401 internal errors. There you said that you solved it. I am also stuck with CloudWaitress, and I am getting 500 as well. Could you tell me how you solved it? That would be very helpful!

Comment: @Chiggiddi For this particular problem it was indeed a problem on my side. I got the 500 error since I was sending the information in the wrong way.
Basically what I needed to change was the payload section. By wrapping it in a variable as in the other thread I got around this 500 error. After that I started getting the 401 error.
I'll post the answer soon.